# How to dynamically load temple in angularjs diretive without ng-include?

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, directive

I want to dynamically load templateUrl in angularjs directive without ng-include.

Answer (score 0):

You can try AngularJS $http 
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

```
<p>Today's welcome message is:</p>
<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("welcome.htm")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I am to do this with directive.